# Directory changed into a regular file upon a UI drag/drop, now how do I change it back?

Tags: ext4, mv, chmod, stat

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04LTS with the latest Linux kernel 4.4.0-206-generic from Canonical (which could be bugged), and I've never seen anything like this before!

Somehow, simply dragging and dropping a directory using the Ubuntu File Manager (which is supposed to be a simple 'mv' command, I believe), something messed up and the directory flag came off the file! So now the contents of my directory are inaccessible.

Forgetting for a moment how this is never supposed to happen, and not sure why it happened, **how do I fix this?** (this is EXT4 file system) I'm afraid to run e2fsck and get these lost chains found and removed or disorganized (there's a lot of files in here)

Help, I can't find any way using 'chmod' to turn on the mode flag that marks the file as a directory. But there has to be a way to transform it back.

See 'stat' on the former directory below.  Ideas how to change it back?

```
$ stat CS_DVD

File: 'CS_DVD'
Size: 38246 Blocks: 80 IO Block: 4096 regular file
Device: 807h/2055d Inode: 3801317 Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--) Uid: ( 1000/ chris) Gid: ( 1000/ chris)
Access: 2021-03-24 14:54:10.639129021 -0400
Modify: 2017-12-01 00:30:20.146519924 -0500
Change: 2021-03-24 15:05:06.307454085 -0400
Birth: -
```

Comment: Sorry, I just figured out what actually happened was this: When you drag in nautilus and hover over a subdirectory, if you don't release the right mouse button quick enough, the context automatically switches to that directory. In this subdirectory, there are additional subdirectories. I released the mouse at the same time this context switch occurred, and at the time of release, my mouse was now over a subdirectory in the subdirectory. Going through those, I found my missing directory and moved it up one level where it was supposed to be.  Nothing funky happened or got lost!

Comment: However, the actual question here is still open: Is there a way the flip the 'directory' status of a file?  What do the raw contents of a directory inode actually look like?